# Destruction of static members inside common classes between two shared objects?

Tags: c++, linker

I have the following hierarchy:

1. classes with multiple static `std::map` that's initialized in cpp as following

```
 std::map<int, string> ClassA::MyStaticMap = ClassA::InitializeMyStaticMap()
```

2. Shared object `libfoo.so` that includes these classes.
3. Shared object `libbar.so` that includes these classes.
4. An application that utilizes the both libraries.

I get crash in the destructors of these maps in the app. The symbols are visible by default, I have not changed the visibility settings.

When I strip the symbols from the so using `-s` option to g++, the crash disappears.

I have a vision on how solve this, not sure which one is better:

1. Keep stripping the symbols table, ( Not sure if there is more implications that I should be aware off ).
2. Move these common things into a 3rd shared object, and make `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so` dynamically link against.

Which one is better ? Also why the crash happens, I am trying to grasp what happens but I can't.

---

**Edit 1**

GCC version: 4.3.3

Target platform: Linux - RH 7.5

Comment: The many joys of globals.  Order of construction fiasco.  Order of destruction disaster.  Can you remove the global and replace it with a singleton getter that returns a reference to a `new`ed `std::map<int, string>` object that that you intentionally leak at program termination?  `std::map<int, string>& GetClassAMap() { static std::map<int, string>* p = new std::map<int, string>(ClassA::InitializeMyStaticMap()); return *p; }`

Comment: @Eljay, your suggestion can be the third option to me, but it is a lot refactoring to do. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The _precise_ reason for this crash can not be deduced without constructing MCVE, and without knowing `g++` version and target platform. And it's hard to give advice (except the general "avoid globals" one) when the reason is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: don't rely on global variables in code exported from a DSO.

```cpp
// from lib foo
class B {
public:
  B(std::map<int, string>& map)
    : a_map_ref(map) {}

  std::map<int, string>& a_map_ref;
};

// from lib bar
class C {
public:
  C(std::map<int, string>& map)
    : a_map_ref(map) {}

  std::map<int, string>& a_map_ref;
};

// in your exe

int main() {

  // Here's my map. I know where it is. I can manage its lifetime
  std::map<int, string> a_map;

  // now I don't care about libFoo initialisation
  {
    loadLibFooDSO();
    {
      B* b = new B(a_map);

      // do thing 
 
      delete b;
    }
    unloadLibFooDSO();
  }

  // now I don't care about libBar initialisation
  {
    loadLibBarDSO();
    {
      C* c = new C(a_map);

      // do thing

 
      delete c;
    }
    unloadLibBarDSO();
  }

  // because my map will correctly be cleaned up on exit
 
  return 0;
}
```

Long answer, there are a plethora of reasons that could be causing this issue. You don't give any info about how ClassA::MyStaticMap is linked into the program, so it's more or less impossible to say.

If it's in a static lib, then both libfoo & libbar will have their own copies of ClassA::MyStaticMap. Whichever lib gets loaded first, will end up owning the instance of ClassA::MyStaticMap (the other will simply use the existing symbol). So if libfoo is loaded first, libber will use libfoo's version of the variable. If libfoo is destroyed first, libbar will attempt to destroy an already destroyed variable.

Simple solution is: DO NOT global export data from DSO's. Keep DSO interfaces as functions only, and you'll usually be OK (ish, there are caveats).

There are other reasons this could be causing a crash, pick any of the following:

1. One DSO is built with debugging enabled, the other is release build.
2. One DSO is built with C++98, the other C++17.
3. One DSO is built with VC++, the other clang.

Comment: Yes, `ClassA::MyStaticMap` is linked statically for `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so`. 
The part of clarifying that each shared object gets its own copy is very helpful for me.

The interfaces of my DSO are functions only, these variables are deeply nested in common functionality between both, maybe around 10 frames down in the back-trace.

What will happen if I did strip the symbol table, then each DSO will use its own copy of the symbols, right ?

Comment: Yup. If you strip the symbols, they'll each use their own version. The interface of your DSO isn't functions only, if you're exporting a global variable, on which more than one DSO relies.

Comment: Just to clarify what you mean by interface ? You mean the exported symbols ? or the APIs I provide in `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so` ? I think you mean the exported symbols.

Comment: No, I mean interface (which by definition, are also exported symbols). If DSO X depends on a symbol you have exported from DSO Y, then changing that symbol in DSO X, breaks DSO Y. Therefore, that symbol _is_ part of your interface.

Comment: Exported globals (and class static vars) are part of a DSO interface. Directly accessible (public) member variables, are also part of a DSO interface. Avoid these at all costs, and try to limit DSO interfaces to be function calls only _(whether member funcs, or static, global 'C' style, constructors, operators, etc)_.

Comment: I got your point, I think I have to dig more info about symbols and how linker work in general. If you have any guidance on this, I would be thankful.
Any way, thanks for your time, you were my hero for today.